# Ruby Debug IDE error : ruby-debug-ide-0.4.9/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:109:in `debug_load'

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rubymine, ruby-debug

I hope someone can assist me. I have RubyMine 2.0.2 installed on Windows 7 32 bit computer. Since a week ago (I presume it must have been after I have update some gems) I cant seem to debug form the IDE. I am trying to debug a rake task which I could before. Running the rake task normally works perfect, just debug doesnt. Its not just limited to the rake, I cant debug any ruby files. I've tried installing older versions of debug-ide and debug-base but to no success. I've tried it with ruby 1.8.7 and 1.8.6 on different computers but nothing. Trying to search the web gave some information, which I've tried, but also no success. Im desperate to get this working. Below are the full error and my current settings:

Error:

```
C:\InstantRails\ruby\bin\ruby.exe -e STDOUT.sync=true;STDERR.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) C:\InstantRails\ruby\bin/rdebug-ide --port 57167 -- C:/InstantRails/rails_apps/paperserve/lib/tasks/poll_snmp.rake
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.9) listens on :57167

C:/InstantRails/rails_apps/paperserve/lib/tasks/poll_snmp.rake:5

C:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.9/lib/ruby-debug ide.rb:109:in `debug_load'

C:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.9/lib/ruby-debug ide.rb:109:in `debug_program'

C:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.9/bin/rdebug-ide:87

C:\InstantRails\ruby\bin/rdebug-ide:19:in `load'

C:\InstantRails\ruby\bin/rdebug-ide:19

-e:1:in `load'

-e:1
Uncaught exception: undefined method `namespace' for main:Object



Process finished with exit code 1
```

Code snippet (It fails at the start of namespace. If I remove this, it fails on the next line, etc, etc)

```
#This script should run every 15 minutes 
require 'snmp' 
require 'yaml'

namespace :cdeweb do
```

RubyGems Environment:

- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7 RUBY VERSION:
- 1.8.6 (2007-09-24 patchlevel 111) [i386-mswin32] INSTALLATION
- DIRECTORY:
- C:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
- RUBY EXECUTABLE:
- C:/InstantRails/ruby/bin/ruby.exe
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY:
- C:/InstantRails/ruby/bin RUBYGEMS
- PLATFORMS:

  - ruby
  - x86-mswin32-60
- GEM PATHS:

  - C:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - C:/Users/Paul.LPFSYSTEMS/.gem/ruby/1.8
- GEM CONFIGURATION:

  - :update_sources => true
  - :verbose => true
  - :benchmark => false
  - :backtrace => false
  - :bulk_threshold => 1000
- REMOTE SOURCES:

  - http://rubygems.org/

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

- actionmailer (2.3.5, 2.0.2)
- actionpack (2.3.5, 2.0.2)
- activerecord (2.3.5, 2.0.2)
- activeresource (2.3.5, 2.0.2)
- activesupport (2.3.5, 2.0.2)
- capistrano (2.5.18, 2.1.0)
- cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
- cmdparse (2.0.2) columnize (0.3.1)
- fxri (0.3.7, 0.3.6) fxruby (1.6.12 mswin32)
- gem_plugin (0.2.3)
- highline(1.5.2, 1.4.0)
- hpricot (0.8.2 x86-mswin32, 0.6 mswin32)
- inaction_mailer (0.6)
- json (1.4.2 x86-mswin32)
- json_pure (1.4.2)
- linecache (0.43 mswin32)
- log4r (1.1.7, 1.0.5)
- mongrel (1.1.5 x86-mswin32-60, 1.1.2 mswin32)
- mysql(2.8.1 x86-mswin32, 2.7.3 mswin32)
- needle (1.3.0)
- net-scp (1.0.2)
- net-sftp (2.0.4, 1.1.0)
- net-ssh (2.0.22, 1.1.2)
- net-ssh-gateway (1.0.1)
- rack (1.0.1)
- rails (2.3.5, 2.0.2)
- rake (0.8.7, 0.8.1, 0.8.0, 0.7.3)
- ruby-debug-base (0.10.3 mswin32)
- ruby-debug-ide (0.4.9)
- ruby-net-ldap (0.0.4)
- rubygems-update (1.3.7, 1.3.6, 1.0.1)
- snmp (1.0.2)
- sources (0.0.1)
- sqlite3-ruby (1.2.5 x86-mswin32, 1.2.1 mswin32)
- win32-api (1.4.6 x86-mswin32-60, 1.0.4 mswin32)
- win32-clipboard (0.5.2, 0.4.3)
- win32-dir (0.3.6, 0.3.2)
- win32-eventlog (0.5.2, 0.4.6)
- win32-file (0.6.3, 0.5.4)
- win32-file-stat (1.3.4, 1.2.7)
- win32-process (0.6.2, 0.5.3)
- win32-sapi (0.1.5, 0.1.4)
- win32-sound (0.4.2, 0.4.1)
- windows-api (0.4.0, 0.2.0)

Comment: I found my answer @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455518/netbeans-6-9-1-rails-3-ruby-1-9-2p0-debugging

second answer add "." to the file

Answer (score 0):

at least ruby-mine 2.0.1 does not work with the latest ruby-debug-ide (0.4.9)

see http://pivotallabs.com/users/david/blog/articles/1167-make-the-rubymine-2-0-1-debugger-work-for-you-

Comment: Thank you. Ive tried this before and it didnt work. I will however try this again, just to make double sure.