# netbeans 6.9.1 + rails 3 + ruby 1.9.2p0 debugging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, netbeans

I'm running OpenSuSE 11.3 and am having problems debugging rails3 application in NetBeans 6.9.1 (ruby 1.9.2p0, rails 3.0.3, rvm).

1. I have installed ruby-debug19, ruby-debug-ide19
2. Changed Gemfile, so that the line *'gem ruby-debug19'* is not commented out
3. Ran *'bundle install'*

When I ran *'ruby s --debugger'* **in console** I got the following:

```
tux@linux-hby6:~/prg/ruby/rail3-sqlite> rails s --debugger
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
=> Debugger enabled
[2010-12-16 01:07:13] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2010-12-16 01:07:13] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2010-08-18) [i686-linux]
[2010-12-16 01:07:13] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=4105 port=3000
```

**NetBeans:**

```
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.9) listens on :35528
        /home/tux/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/ruby-debug-ide19-0.4.12/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:123:in `debug_load'
        /home/tux/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/ruby-debug-ide19-0.4.12/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:123:in `debug_program'
        /home/tux/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/ruby-debug-ide19-0.4.12/bin/rdebug-ide:87:in `'
        /home/tux/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/rdebug-ide:19:in `load'
        /home/tux/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/rdebug-ide:19:in `'
Uncaught exception: no such file to load -- script/rails
```

Any ideas how can I solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: This solved the problem for me http://blog.blakesimpson.co.uk/view/20-fix-fast-debugger-ruby-debug-ide-on-windows-7 Also useful pdf - there is a list of gems on page 6 for debuger http://csc.columbusstate.edu/woolbright/class/wkenna.pdf

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have found the solution! This [post](http://noteslog.com/post/netbeans-6-9-1-ruby-1-9-2-rails-3-0-0-debugging/) gave me some hints.

my platform: ruby 1.9.2-p136, rails 3.0.3, netbeans 7.0 beta

file: ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/ruby-debug-ide19-0.4.12/bin/rdebug-ide:79

```
script = ARGV.shift
Debugger::PROG_SCRIPT = (script =~ /script([\\\/])rails/ ? Dir.pwd + $1 : '') + script
puts Debugger::PROG_SCRIPT
#Debugger::PROG_SCRIPT = ARGV.shift
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this thread at the netbeans's forums. It worked for me:

http://forums.netbeans.org/post-93244.html

The post:

```
The problem is the missing path . in $:, so the scripts aren't found.
I inserted
$: << "."
before the load command in rdebug-ide (/usr/bin/rdebug-ide).
It fixed the problem.
(NetBeans 6.9.1, ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18) [x86_64-linux])
_________________
tiesel
```

its the answer